# Send file to api and get null in controller

Tags: jquery, spring-boot

I send file to api as follows

```
const formData = new FormData();
    if ($.isEmptyObject(this.state.attachment)===false) {
        formData.append('attachment', this.state.attachment);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST + "/api/attachment",
            async: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                attachment: formData
            }
        });
    }
```

And attachment I get the following way

```
<input type='file' name='attachment' className="form-control" defaultValue={this.state.attachment}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

And my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpEntity attachment(@ModelAttribute MultipartFile attachment){
    System.out.println(attachment);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I get null in result
What can be wrong i doing?

**Update**

```
    handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
};
```

Comment: Please post your handleChange() function so that I can look inside what's actually going inside the this.state.attachment.

Comment: Send the FormData object directly: `data: formData`. Don't wrap it in an object to be serialised.

Comment: Create a wrapper object with a field named `attachment` of type `MultipartFile`. Then use `@ResponseBody` as an annotation on that object as a method argument.

Comment: Comment M. Deinum not work. And i confused but update post for comment root